# Generalised select query with multiple values

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a select query in MySQL which display all column names with checkboxes in the frontend form and allow the user to choose which of to use in the select query. I am OK with using $_POST to post across the values but I'm not sure how I can put these into my query string correctly as some users may select 1, while others may select 3.

This is what I have so far:

Front end form:

```
<form action="back.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="person" value="forename">Forename<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="person" value="surname">Surname<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="person" value="nationality">Nationality<br>
</form>
```

Back end:

```
$person=$_POST["person"];

$query = "select" . $person . " from Actor WHERE nationality = British";
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: mysql uses the `limit` keyword to control the size of the output for instance `select * from Employee limit 10` will return 10 records. i assume this was your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an array so that `$_POST["person"]` will be an array:

```
<form action="back.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="person[]" value="forename">Forename<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="person[]" value="surname">Surname<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="person[]" value="nationality">Nationality<br>
</form>
```

Then on the php-side you need to validate your input. You cannot automatically escape or prepare column names so you would need to check each element against a white-list.

Something like:

```
// your valid column names
$valid_column_names = array('forename', ...);

$validated_array = array();
foreach ($_POST["person"] as $value)
{
   if (in_array($value, $valid_column_names))
   {
      $validated_array[] = $value;
   }
}
```

Then you can simply implode the validated, non-empty array and use it in your query:

```
$query = "select `" . implode('`,`', $validated_array) . "` from Actor WHERE nationality = British";
```

Note that I added a space after `select` (you need that) and backticks to quote the field names (not necessary in your example but necessary in case of reserved words, etc.).